# How do I hide Linux partitions from Windows on a USB with multiple partitions?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, partitioning

I have a USB drive with an ext4 partition and an ESP for Ventoy so I can have multiple bootable ISO images on one drive. I also have an NTFS partition on it that I use to store files on. When I plug in the USB drive on Windows, I get several prompts asking me to format the partitions and the partitions show up in explorer as empty drives, except for the NTFS partitions which works as intended. I want to hide the extra partitions from Windows and get rid of the prompts on every computer I plug it into. I have to use this drive on many different computers, so removing the drive letter won’t work. I also tried setting GPT flags, including flags 62 and 63 to hide the drive, and those didn’t work either.

**UPDATE:** I posted the answer below

Comment: You are probably using the wrong partition type UUID. Use one other than `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` (aliased with type code `0x0700` in `gdisk`) (e.g. `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4`, which is aliased with type code `0x8300` in `gdisk`). Make sure you don't confuse it with partition UUID or filesystem UUID.

Comment: I am using type code `8300` for my ext4 partition. I set it with `gdisk`

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of `Disk Management`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Windows only uses flags 62 and 63 if it's a basic data partition (type code `0700`). I changed the type code on the ext4 partiton and set flags 62 and 63 and now it doesn't show up in explorer.